# A ton of errors related to messy OOP code

Tags: c++, oop

I'm getting *loads* of errors with this when I compile. Hopefully things will become clearer for me if I solve one of them (if not then I can post the rest):

`'Weapon' : illegal member initialization: 'Name' is not a base or member`

It has that for Name and Cost. Weapon inherits Shopable, and Shopable has Name, Cost and Description in its protected section.

Shopable.h:

```
#ifndef _SHOPABLE_H_
#define _SHOPABLE_H_

#include "Library.h"

class Shopable{
protected:
    std::string Name;
    int Cost;
    std::string Description;
public:
    std::string getName() const{return Name;}
    int getCost() const {return Cost;}
    virtual std::string getDesc() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

Weapon.h:

```
#ifndef _WEAPON_H_
#define _WEAPON_H_

#include "Shopable.h"

class Weapon : public Shopable{
private:
    int Damage;
public:
    Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n) : Cost(c), Damage(d), Name(n){}
    std::string getDesc() const{
        return getName()+"\t"+tostring(Damage)+"\t"+tostring(Cost);
    }
    int getDamage() const{return Damage;}
    int DamageTarget(Entity* target){
        int DamageDealt = 0;
        //do damage algorithm things here
        return DamageDealt;
    }
};

#endif
Library.h:

#ifndef _LIBRARY_
#define _LIBRARY_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

//file includes
#include "Globals.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Exception.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Armour.h"
#include "Consumable.h"

//prototypes that require "Library.h"
bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player *player);
bool PoglathonTown(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player *player);

std::map<std::string,Weapon*> init_weapons(void);
std::map<std::string,Armour*> init_armour(void);
std::map<std::string,Consumable*> init_consumables(void);

#endif //__LIBRARY__
```

Globals.h:

```
//global variables
#ifndef _GLOBAL_
#define _GLOBAL_

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//prototypes
void NPCTalk(std::string const& speaker,std::vector<std::string> const& text);
void wait(double seconds);
void regionChange(int amount);
int getPositionInStringVector(std::vector<std::string> const& vec,std::string value);


//variables


//defines
#define RegionChange 3

////tostring
template <class TYPE> std::string tostring(const TYPE & t ) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
};

#endif //__GLOBAL__
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only initialize members of the *current* class in an initialization list.  `Name` (and `Cost`) are both members of the base class; they must be initialized in the base-class constructor.

The simplest way to do that is to add a constructor to `Shopable`:

```
class Shopable {
    ...
public:
    Shopable(std::string n, int c, std::string d)
    : Name(n), Cost(c), Description(d) {}
    ...
};
```

and then use that in the `Weapon` initialization list:

```
class Weapon : public Shopable {
    ...
public:
    Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n)
    : Shopable(n,c,""), Damage(d)
    {}
};
```

Comment: How would I make a constructor that initialises all 3?

Comment: @pighead Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n) { Cost = c; Damage = d; Name = n;} will do

Comment: @J.S. Taylor: That would work, but there's a much better, more general, solution available.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n) : Cost(c), Damage(d), Name(n){}
```

you cannot use members of the base class in the initialization list. Instead, define a proper constructor in `Shoppable` and call it like this:

```
Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n) : Shoppable(c, d, n)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make a constructor for Shopable and use that to initialize the inherited members.

```
class Shopable{
protected:
    std::string Name;
    int Cost;
    std::string Description;
public:
    std::string getName() const{return Name;}
    int getCost() const {return Cost;}
    virtual std::string getDesc() const = 0;
public:
    Shopable(std::string n, int c, std::string d) : Name(n), Cost(c), Description(d) {}
};
```

and

```
class Weapon : public Shopable{
private:
    int Damage;
public:
    Weapon(int c,int d,std::string n) : Shopable(n, c, "Weapon"), Damage(d) {} // should probably reorder the parameters to match, just for consistency
    std::string getDesc() const{
        return getName()+"\t"+tostring(Damage)+"\t"+tostring(Cost);
    }
    int getDamage() const{return Damage;}
    int DamageTarget(Entity* target){
        int DamageDealt = 0;
        //do damage algorithm things here
        return DamageDealt;
    }
};
```